# No plugin found for prefix 'android' in the current project

Tags: android, maven

I have started since 2 days learning Maven & using goals as deploy and install.So I hv used this command:

> mvn install android:deploy

Note:clean,install commands work fine

this is what I get:

> [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'android' in the current project
>   and in the plugin groups [com.cryptolog.maven.plugins,
>   org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the
>   repositories [local (/home/yougostt/.m2/repository), central

and this is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>univer.lib.androidtestxmlrpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>android_xmlrpc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.cryptolog.rpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>libxmlrpc</artifactId>
        <version>${rpc.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.cryptolog.rpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>libxmlrpc-client</artifactId>
        <version>${rpc.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<properties>
  <rpc.version>3.7</rpc.version>
</properties>
</project>
```

How can I fix it please?

Comment: How did u fixed this?

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you are using the `com.simpligilty.maven.plugins` [Android Maven Plugin](http://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin) (but the same would also work for any other plugin), you can add to your pom the following (as also explained by its [official usage page](http://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin/usage.html):

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.simpligility.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.1</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

---

If instead you are using the Jayway Androind Maven Plugin, the configuration would look like (as also explained by the official [Spring guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/maven-android):

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0-rc.1</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```